# Получить значение элемента массива по индексу другого

Tags: javascript

дано: 
два массива

```
arr = [4, 2, 3, 1]
arr2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

у меня такая задача: нужно взять значение в первом массиве и найти элемент с этим индексом из второго элемента, и так до тех пор пока не закончится массив.

к примеру, вот так:

```js
let arr = [4, 2, 1, 3];
let arr2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let a = arr[0];
let b = arr2[3];
let c = (a = b);
console.log(c);
```

но как это сделать циклично?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let arr = [4, 2, 1, 3];
let arr2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
arr.forEach(element => {
  console.log(arr2[element - 1]);
});
```

-1 потому как нумерация элементов в массиве с нуля

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы очень помогли

Answer (score 2):

```js
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
    console.log(arr2[arr[i] - 1])
}
```